# NUSOAP Client response is empty when I call SOAP endpoint on upgraded server

Tags: php, nusoap

I am using NUSOAP client with a hard coded XML request to communicate with a Server to read a response from a Websphere server. I use nusoap_client->send to send the request.

$result = nusoap_client->send.
Then SOAP response is obtained from $result. Perfect.
Now I am trying to get a server response from an upgraded server (probably not using Websphere. Not sure). SOAP namespace is also changed and the response has some prefix.

I no longer get the SOAP response from $result (when I run strlen() I get zero size) . But I can call nusoap_client->responseData to get a response below. So I try to parse with simplexml_load_string on PHP5.x but it doesnt seem to parse and error message => syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING. Where could I be going wrong?

```
$stringer = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:getCarResourceResponse xmlns:ser="http://sos.joburg.com/webservice/ecare/services">
            <ser:GetCarResourceReply>
                <ser:resCode>10652981251</ser:resCode>
                <ser:departName>Ingolstadt</ser:departName>
                <ser:resStatus>4</ser:resStatus>
                <ser:statusDate>2022-05-09 09:24:50</ser:statusDate>
                <ser:isScheduled>0</ser:isScheduled>
                <ser:departStatus>0</ser:departStatus>
            </ser:GetCarResourceReply>
            <ser:ResultOfOperationReply>
                <ser:resultCode>0</ser:resultCode>
                <ser:resultMessage>Successful</ser:resultMessage>
            </ser:ResultOfOperationReply>
        </ser:getCarResourceResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
    XML;
$log->logInfo(print_r(simplexml_load_string($stringer), 1));
```

Comment: is the second last line `XML;` in the codeblock included in the response from the server? If so, then this is likely the error and you've to strip it away before parsing.

Comment: The syntax error you mention is an error in your **PHP** syntax, not in the XML. Most likely you made a typo somewhere.

Comment: @David That's part of the PHP, it just wasn't showing properly because the markdown wasn't quite right.

Comment: sorry I see now, ok.

Comment: Apologies for my poor showing in the code insert. It has been a while. Problem solved. I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to this, I found the solution. Effectively, while I want to take an unstructured XML output and make it structured, it doesn't work like I thought.

It was necessary for me to take the single line of XML and format it as you see in the code markup. In the text file I lifted this from, I lifted a single line of XML which was not structured into multiple lines you see in stack overflow.

Thank you for your comments.